# how to manage views in normal layout for 4.6inch and 3.7 inch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have implemented layout folder from layout-small to layout-xlarge.
but for nexus one and nexus s play pause buttons are get arranged automatically and look differently and for galaxy nexus and samsung s3 buttons are get arranged differently But both are using same xml that default normal.. small and large and xlarge are working fine.
anybody knows how can i arrange item so it look same on both device...

I want it to look like this 
[image]

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/play_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ff"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/test_play_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/metadata"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="WUMM - D Light "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/like"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="default Like" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/metadata"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ch_play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/play"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/play"
        android:background="@drawable/back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/play"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play"
        android:background="@drawable/forward" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

BUT IY LOOKs LIKE THIS on NEXUS ONE and S
Here is nexus one image 
[image]

and here is galaxy nexus screen shot 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you go through this tutorial, Here, you can learn multiple screen sizes or resoultion support

[Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Screen Size Support](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Designing Images, Icon For Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Comment: i have created xlarge , large , large , small folder in res and change the xml content according to folder..but my problem is for nexus s and one buttons are get aligned different automatically and for galaxy nexus buttons are get aligned different ... both screens takes xml from normal layout (default) so making large and small folder it doesnt work for me..any other solution